# How to iterate Roles in IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> and display role names in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Am using Identity 2.1.0 with MVC and razor Views. One of my views gets a list of all users with this GET Controller Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Users()
{
    return View(await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync());
}
```

Within the View there is a foreach that iterates through each user and displays the usual information like email address, username, etc. I would like to know if there is also a way of iterating through the roles for each user so that I can display the role membership of each user something like this:

```
Customer
Employee
```

I haven't been able to figure this out. Part of my problem is that I don't have any Intellisense within razor views and haven't been able to find anything helpful on Google.

The View Model is `@model IEnumerable<XXXX_My_App.Models.ApplicationUser>`. ApplicationUser has a base class of IdentityUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a custom ViewModel which contains the user itself and the roles he is member of. An implementation could look like the following:

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Users()
{
    var users = UserManager.Users;
    var model = new Collection<UserRoleViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
        var rolesCollection = new Collection<IdentityRole>();

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var role = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
            rolesCollection.Add(role);
        }

        model.Add(new UserRoleViewModel { User = user, Roles = rolesCollection });
    }

    return View("Users", model);
}
```

**UserRoleViewModel**

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public Collection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

With that you can use the following model in your view to iterate over the appropriate properties

```
@model ICollection<YourProject.Models.UserRoleViewModel>
```

Comment: My one line of code to return an IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> kind of blew up, but I think you are right. I wasn't sure how to code the ViewModel, but you made it very clear. Thank you for taking the time to show how this can be done.

Comment: Horizon_Net, there are some errors in your example code, although you surely pointed me in a good direction (rolesConnection vs rolesCollection, etc). Also, each `user` has a `Roles` that contains a list of all user Ids in the Role - overkill, but I'll work with this. There isn't any functional purpose for the RoleNames - they are for display only and all I need is the RoleName. In the View I had previously been able to display column headings with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)`. This is no longer valid obviously. How would I get the column name using this new model?

Comment: Just us IntelliSense. You can access the properties like this ```@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.UserName)```.

Comment: I'm unable to get Intellisense in .cshtml. I can't step through or set breakpoints either. I've tried everything I can think of including uninstall and reinstall of VS 2013.2. So, I have a hindrance on that point. I did figure it out though. Thx!

Comment: Tthanks for this. I needed to add 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True;' to the ConnectionString.

Answer (score 0):

If your Usermanager is returning a list of identityusers and so each identityuser should have a roles property which you should be able to enumerate. However this will only be populated if your implementation includes a class which implements IRoleStore but you haven't provided details of your implementation so we can only guess.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Hargrovm, there is a .Roles property and I am able to iterate through it to output the RoleId property. I'm trying to figure out now how to get the RoleName for RoleId.

Comment: I'm surprised you can't get at the role.name if you can get the id -I don't know enough - I've only done a little with identity and then it was 1.0 however there is a rolemanager so perhaps you can use the id with the rolemanager to get an instance of the role. It does seem like a lot of effort for something so obvious. Roles should return TRole where TRole:identityrole  and identity role should have name and Id properties so I don't know. Rolemanager should have a findbyidasync method.

Comment: The UserManager class has all of those methods in my app. I modeled it from an Identity 2.0 sample application. UserManager also has the RoleStore. ApplicationUser in my app contains a .Roles which contains RoleId and UserId. I could create a new model for this View, but I'm just trying to figure out what needs to happen inside a razor view to get a RoleName from RoleId. And yes, most of the examples I've seen have a .Name property...