# Web API 2 Entity Framework Return list of users with roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am working with EF/Web API.  I am new to EF.  I want to get a list of users from the aspnetusers table along with the user roles.

For instance, the sample JSON that I would like to see.

```json
[
  {
    "UserId": "sample string 1",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Email": "sample string 3",
    "Username": "sample string 4",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Id": "safdsdafadsf",
        "Name": "Reader"
      },
      {
        "Id": "sdfskjadhf",
        "Name": "Writer"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

I followed the advise on this thread 
[ASP.NET 4.5 WebAPI to return list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117210/asp-net-4-5-webapi-to-return-list-of-users)

This works for getting the aspnetuser table info, but when I try to add in roles, I get errors on the user.Roles
Message "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."  I am using the default user management scheme that is created when building a new Web API project in Visual Studio.

Here is my code.

```
    public IEnumerable<UserListBindingModel> GetUsers()
    {

        List<UserListBindingModel> userList = new List<UserListBindingModel>();
        foreach (ApplicationUser user in UserManager.Users)
        {
            userList.Add(new UserListBindingModel
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                Enabled = user.enabled,
                Username = user.UserName,
                Email = user.Email,
                Roles = user.Roles

        });
        }
        return userList;
    }
```

Comment: This post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588758/how-to-iterate-roles-in-ienumerableapplicationuser-and-display-role-names-in-r

Comment: The EF is not closing connection properly on multiple data retrieval commands executed on single connection. Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma OR just adding ToList() at the end will solve your problem as it will forces the DataContext to complete the read operation, freeing the connection up to perform another action.